# Method for saving 1000+ objects in Android through multiple lifecycles

Tags: android, json, android-intent, parcelable, serializable

I am creating an Android application (in Java) and am trying to save objects between lifecycles and make certain that they are saved, even after onDestroy() might be called. From my research there appears to be 3 ways to save objects long-term.

1) Serialization 2) Parcelable 3) JSON (specifically via Gson)

Furthermore, I must pass these objects between activities. I know that Parcelable is not really meant for saving objects, and Serialization is very slow in Android, and may not be geared towards passing via Intents. I am not that familiar with Gson as of yet.

I want a means of saving objects which is also forgiving (that is, I can edit the structure of the objects between release updates and not render previous Objects useless, or am able to restore said objects to the newer version).

Is JSON (specifically via Gson) the best way for me to go about persisting my Objects through lifecycles as well as passing my objects via intents?

Thank you!

Comment: I am aware that this answer kind of answers my question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7356157/2514524) . However, it does not appear to specify whether the object implements both Parcelable and Serializable (which I did not think was possible) as well as use JSON.

Comment: I would just use POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) and an SQLite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not necessarily Json data, but perhaps XML, or even just raw text data that can be stored on the SD Card, or Internal storage if an SD Card isn't present would work. As long as the user doesn't remove your data, there shouldn't be any issues with storing data that way.

From there, even if you did decide to change something about how you store your data, you could write a converter that detects deprecated data and would upgrade it.

Also on a side note, you may want to use the intent to pass a message to the other activity to do something with the stored data instead of passing a bunch of data through the intent pipeline.

A message could be something as simple as a string, or perhaps even an integer, that can be interpreted by the receiving activity in order to complete a set of actions.

Comment: Excellent! But would a converter be able to work (or could you supply a link as an example)? In my mind, in order for me to tell if an Object needed to be converted, I would first need to call that object and I would be unable to do so if it were incompatible with the new version of the generic.

Comment: You are thinking too narrow. You are defining the structure of your data, what xml tags go where, or where the data is located in json. A converter would simply restructure the data if you needed it to be changed, or if, down the road, you decided to switch from json to xml. Also, signaling an activity to do something shouldn't really involve objects. While yes, you should use objects to contain the data, all you need to do is implement a wrapper that will parse a message from another activity, then act upon the data using the object you have defined.

Comment: Okay, I guess I will understand what you are saying about restructuring data better as I go along. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be the objects saved?  Could you save data as files?  Have you considered the standard file API:  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html.

You could also use SQLite http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

If you need an ORM for mapping your saved data to objects:  http://droidparts.org/orm.html or http://droidparts.org/orm.html  or http://greendao-orm.com/ or http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

Comment: Thanks for the numerous links! I had actually viewed most of those before, though I was not previously familiar with ORM.